# How do I stop Visual Studio from enlarging controls every time I open a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have one windows form file that each time I open it in Visual Studio it increases the size of the controls within the designer file.  If I save the form, close it in the editor, and open it again, then the controls are all a little larger than before.  I can see that the size properties on the controls are all increasing within the designer file.

Can anyone explain to me how to fix this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like the size is being adjusted as a side effect in one of your public properties. Are you explicitly setting/modifying sizes in your form anywhere?  Are these usercontrols on your form?

Comment: Check out properties: AutoScaleMode, AutoSize, AutoSizeMode

Comment: do you have a high dpi setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, when the designer loads/saves your form, it is going to call the getters/setters on the public properties of your Form and the Form's controls.

This means that if you've overridden a property of the form, and accessing/setting said property has a side effect of resizing a control, that size adjustment will be reflected in the designer.  Then when you save the form, that new size is persisted to the designer-generated code.  Each time you reopen the form, this adjustment would occur.

This would also apply to event handlers for properties that are being set within the designer-generated code.

Comment: I found the issue.  I had created a custom control that inherited from SplitContainer.  Visual Studio automatically created a designer file for the custom control that set the AutoScaleMode property to Font (Why? I don't know).  This caused the size of everything within the SplitContainer to be increased each time.

Answer (score 3):

I've had problems with visual studio when running on windows 8 with an HD res laptop vs a regular 1280 x 800 one

The windows default on a fresh install for the HD laptop was to increase font size in windows programs by 25%

Look under Screen Resolution -> Make text or other items larger or smaller -> Select 'Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays' to see the setting. 125% in my case.

Visual studio seems to set the form or controls AutoScaleMode setting based on the setting above.

In the form designer: 
On low res laptop
 this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);

Hi res
 this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 16F);

Answer (score 0):

Just lock your controls so that you can't accidentally move or resize them.

Just open the form designer, right click and from the context menu choose "Lock Controls".

[image]

As to why Visual Studio is resizing them automatically, I can only guess.